# Beginner Rust Todo app

Tags: beginner, rust

I am trying to use the practices that I have learnt from the rust book. Any advice is welcome. Please feel free to be as nitpicky as possible.

```rs
use std::fmt;
use std::io::{self, Write};

struct Item {
    name: String,
    done: bool,
}
impl fmt::Display for Item {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{} [{}]", self.name, if self.done { 'X' } else { ' ' })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut todos: Vec<Item> = Vec::new();

    loop {
        let mut input = String::new();
        print!("> ");
        io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input)
            .expect("Failed to read line");
        let tokens: Vec<&str> = input.trim().split_whitespace().collect();

        match tokens[..] {
            ["add", item_name] => {
                let item_name = String::from(item_name);
                println!("Added item: {item_name}");
                let item = Item {
                    name: item_name,
                    done: false,
                };
                todos.push(item);
            }

            ["remove", item_name] => {
                let item_name = String::from(item_name);
                if let Some(index) = todos.iter().position(|x| (*x).name == item_name) {
                    todos.remove(index);
                }
                println!("Removed item: {item_name}");
            }

            ["toggle", item_name] => {
                let item_name = String::from(item_name);
                if let Some(index) = todos.iter().position(|x| (*x).name == item_name) {
                    todos[index].done = !todos[index].done
                }
            }

            ["show"] => {
                for item in todos.iter() {
                    println!("   {item}");
                }
            }

            ["exit"] => {
                println!("Exited applciation");
                break;
            }
            _ => println!("invalid input"),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Use `cargo clippy` to find common mistakes:

### Redundant `trim`

In `input.trim().split_whitespace()` you can remove the `trim()`, since `split_whitespace` already ignores leading and trailing whitespace.

### Unnecessary deref

In this closure: `|x| (*x).name == item_name)`, you can remove the `*` since the compiler will dereference it automatically.

### Explicit `iter()`

It's more idiomatic to write `&todos` instead of `todos.iter()`.

## Unnnecessary `String` creation

This line is repeated throughout your `match` arms:
`let item_name = String::from(item_name);`.
However, in most arms, you can elide it, since you can compare directly against the `&str` `item_name`.

## Simpler `Vec` initialization

In the line `let mut todos: Vec<Item> = Vec::new();`, you can remove the explicit type and call the `vec!` macro for more concise code:
`let mut todos = vec![];`

## Typo

`applciation` should be `application`.

## Inaccurate output

When removing an element, you always print a sucess message. It would make more sense to only print it inside the `if` so it only is shown after really removing an element.
Additionally, a sucessful `toggle` should also get a sucess message for consistency.

## `eprintln!` for errors

Errors should be printed to stderr via `eprintln!` and not via `println!`.

## Final code

```rust
use std::fmt;
use std::io::{self, Write};

struct Item {
    name: String,
    done: bool,
}
impl fmt::Display for Item {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{} [{}]", self.name, if self.done { 'X' } else { ' ' })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut todos = vec![];

    loop {
        let mut input = String::new();
        print!("> ");
        io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input)
            .expect("Failed to read line");
        let tokens: Vec<&str> = input.split_whitespace().collect();

        match tokens[..] {
            ["add", item_name] => {
                let item = Item {
                    name: String::from(item_name),
                    done: false,
                };
                todos.push(item);
                println!("Added item: {item_name}");
            }

            ["remove", item_name] => {
                if let Some(index) = todos.iter().position(|x| x.name == item_name) {
                    todos.remove(index);
                    println!("Removed item: {item_name}");
                }
            }

            ["toggle", item_name] => {
                if let Some(index) = todos.iter().position(|x| x.name == item_name) {
                    todos[index].done = !todos[index].done;
                    println!("Toggled item: {item_name}");
                }
            }

            ["show"] => {
                for item in &todos {
                    println!("   {item}");
                }
            }

            ["exit"] => {
                println!("Exited application");
                break;
            }
            _ => eprintln!("invalid input"),
        }
    }
}
```

## Further ideas

- Consider adding a `help` command for easier usage.
- Consider adding support for saving the todos to and loading them from a file to preserve state over multiple runs.

Comment: Hello, I was trying to implement saving as you said. First I thought I could save it as a csv but people pointed out to me that it has too many edge cases. I was told to use something like sqlite. But that seems like overkill for a simple data like this. Do you have any recommendations? Especially something I can do without external modules.

Comment: If you really want to avoid external libraries, you will probably have to use your own custom format for storing this and convert the todos to this format manually. But the simplest approach may be to use json (via the serde and serde_json libraries), since it's very convenient to serialize and deserialize Rust objects into json with them.

Answer (score 7):

This looks good!  There’s no One True Coding Style, but since you seemed to be interested in fluent style, with iterators, I’ll go into how you could refactor that way.

Let’s factor out the part of the code that parses and executes the commands into a helper function.  Let’s call it `todo_cmd` for now.  The `main()` function can now become:

```
fn main() {
    io::stdin()
        .lines()                                 // Iterator over io::Result<String>
        .map(io::Result::unwrap)                 // Iterator over String
        .try_fold(Vec::<Item>::new(), todo_cmd); // Accumulates to an Option<Vec<Item>>
}
```

Much shorter, and the pattern we’re using is very explicit.

The [`Iterator::try_fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold) method is a little obscure, but what it does is take a state object, here initialized to an empty `Vec::item`, and pass it to a function, together with the next item in the sequence.  In functional programming, a `fold` would return the new state, to be passed to the function next time.  The classic example is to calculate a sum with

```
.fold(0, |accumulator, term| accumulator + term)
```

or a product with

```
.fold(1, |accumulator, term| accumulator * term)
```

But this is `try_fold`.  It’s different because it passes the state (the current vector of items) to a function that *possibly* returns an updated state, but might also fail.  If the function ever fails to return a state, the iteration stops.  So the function signature is something similar to:

```
fn todo_cmd(mut todos: Vec<Item>, line: String) -> Option<Vec<Item>>
```

The motivation here is that there’s a command that stops the program, `exit`.  If we get this command, we should return `None`.  Otherwise, we should update `todos` and return the updated value.  (Since `todos` is owned, this will move, and not copy, it.)

An implementation that works, and stays close to what you wrote (but which you could definitely improve on—it’s not very efficient):

```
fn todo_cmd(mut todos: Vec<Item>, line: String) -> Option<Vec<Item>> {
    print!("> ");
    io::stdout().flush().unwrap();

    if let Some(("", untrimmed)) = line.split_once("add ") {
        let trimmed = untrimmed.trim();
        todos.push(Item {
            name: trimmed.to_string(),
            done: false,
        });
        println!("Added item: {}", trimmed);
        Some(todos)
    } else if let Some(("", untrimmed)) = line.split_once("remove") {
        let trimmed = untrimmed.trim();
        if let Some(i) = todos.iter().position(|s| s.name == trimmed) {
            todos.remove(i);
            println!("Removed: {}", trimmed);
        } else {
            eprintln!("Could not find: {}", trimmed)
        }
        Some(todos)
    } else if let Some(("", untrimmed)) = line.split_once("toggle") {
        let trimmed = untrimmed.trim();
        if let Some(i) = todos.iter().position(|s| s.name == trimmed) {
            todos[i].done = !todos[i].done;
            println!("Set to {}: {}", todos[i].done, trimmed);
        } else {
            eprintln!("Could not find: {}", trimmed)
        }
        Some(todos)
    } else if "show" == line.trim() {
        todos.iter().for_each(|item| println!("{}", item));
        Some(todos)
    } else if "exit" == line.trim() {
        None
    } else {
        eprintln!("Unknown command: {}", line.trim());
        Some(todos)
    }
}
```

The main change to functionality is printing error messages to standard error.  There are a small handful of clean-ups, such as removing a few `let` declarations.

There are several other ways to do it, for example, checking for `exit` with `take_while` and passing the resulting sequence to `for_each`.

Also keep this up top:

```
use std::fmt;
use std::io::{self, Write};

struct Item {
    name: String,
    done: bool,
}
impl fmt::Display for Item {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{} [{}]", self.name, if self.done { 'X' } else { ' ' })
    }
}
```